# How to do Angular2 work with templates?

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-routing, mean-stack, angular2-directives

I am trying to use templates with Angular2 and it is not working as expected. Here is what I have tried so far. Does anyone have any ideas or maybe another way that I could approach it?

First of all, I am using MEAN stack that express generates an index.html, nodejs creates the templates and angular is the app.

index.html

```
{includes header.tpl}
<scripts> ... </scripts>
<my-app> Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
{includes footer.tpl}
```

Inside my header.tpl I have some directives that I would like angular app interpret them

header.tpl

```
<html> 
   <header> ... </header>
   <body>
       <div *ngIf='user.status === "new" '> ADDED THIS </div>
   ...
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello</h1> <div *ngIf='user.status === "new"'> ADDED THIS 2 </div>`,
})

export class AppComponent {

     public user:any = {};

     constructor(@Inject(ActivatedRoute) public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
          this.checkParams();
     }

    private checkParams() {
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            if (!!params['status'] && params['status'] === 'new') {
                this.user.status = 'new';
                console.log('I am new');
            } else {
                console.log('I am NOT new');
                this.user.status = 'old';
            }
            console.log('user', this.user);
        });
    }
}
```

When I access my application by

> domain.com?status=new

only shows 'ADDED THIS 2', but I also want to show 'ADDED THIS'. As you can see, 'ADDED THIS 2' is running inside `<my-app>` and 'ADDED THIS' outside.

So any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple this won't work. The code of your header isn't inside the `my-app` tags, so Angular won't pick up on it of course.

Everything that you want to be rendered by Angular needs to be inside the root tags of you app or in a component of the app.

Comment: Hi @Maarten Tibau, this option was already tested and didn't work too.

Comment: Yea, but inside of the `my-app` tags I would also think it won't work, because Angular doesn't use a template engine or anything.

Maybe you would be able to solve it with some Webpack plugin, maybe something like this?

[html-tpl-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-tpl-loader)